# Yii2: How to check condition before model creation

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model          = new Bookings();
    $temp           = new RoomTypes();
    $roomtype = $model->room_type;
    $checkRoomModel = RoomTypes::find()->where(['room_type' => $room_type])->one();

    $totalremain = $temp->total_remain;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
    {
        if ($checkRoomModel->totalremain > 0) 
        {
                $imageName   = $model->first_name;
                $mobile      = $model->primary_mobile;
                $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
                $model->file->saveAs('uploads/id_images/' . $imageName . '_' . $mobile . '.' . $model->file->extension);
                //save the path in the db column
                $model->id_image = 'uploads/id_images/' . $imageName . '_' . $mobile . '.' . $model->file->extension;
                $model->save();
                Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE room_types SET total_booked = total_booked + 1  WHERE room_type = '$model->room_type'")->execute();
                Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE room_types SET total_remain = total_remain - 1   WHERE room_type = '$model->room_type'")->execute();
            } else {
                echo "This room Types are full ";
            }

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'temp'  => $temp,
        ]);
    }
}
```

in database there is column total_remain and total_booked, i need to validate before actioncreate() that total_remain of  $model->room_type is not equal zero

How to do this?

Comment: which model have the column total_remain and total_booked?

Comment: `RoomTypes()` has it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run it before the action you can use before action

```
    public function beforeAction($event)
    {
        if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
                if ($this->action->id == 'create') {
                   $roomModel = RoomTypes::find()->where( [   'room_type' => $room_type ])->one();
                   if($roomModel->totalremain) > 0) 
                   {
                        return false;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        return true;
                   }
                }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is a select of the related model and then drive you code to the right activiti

```
public function actionCreate()
   {
       $model = new Bookings();
       $temp  = new RoomTypes();
       $checkRoomModel = RoomTypes::find()->where( [   'room_type' => $room_type ])->one();
       if ( $checkRooModel->totalremain) > 0 {
               ....
```

Comment: can i set flash message before submitting the form?

Comment: @you can also perform the check direcly in the view  (adding the proper use model .. or you can perform an ajax validation .. .. and then invoke a proper alert or message to the user .. (the flash in managed by submit ..and showed when you render a page .. )

Comment: can you please help me with the code, I need to submit this tomorrow in college

Comment: Well if you need for tomorrow the simplest way is generate a proper flash not before the actionCreate but inside the action create .. and then perform the check if it's allright the save .. otherwise render a porper signal page with the flash message ..

Comment: i have updated the question  please have a look, is it right?

Comment: I don't know because you obtain value for new model and i don't know if you have funtion for assign this value ...normally a new model is an empty model ... and second you have use the code i have suggested but i don't know if this code is right for you ..

Comment: it will be simple check, but dont know how to do

Comment: can i do like , i should not allow user to create record, as soon as user select particular room type from drop down it should alert like "Can not book this room type"

Comment: OK ... The problem for me is undertand two things ...the firts is how you obtain the proper value about total_remain and total_booked for each room_type ..? and the second is kwon if you very good with ajax (jquery post ... and javascript ) ?

Comment: I imagined for this is i think  then is not easy to manage client side check (or validatio) like you like and show a proper message client side .. for this i suggested a check server side and a proper render message page

Comment: i really dont know how to do this :(

Comment: i'm sorry but is late night  for me .. ..if you need i can delete my answer so someone else could help you ..

Comment: dont delete the answer

Comment: structurally yes is correct ... but repeat i don't know is this is correct for your model and data ..